# Input of email and url to be clickable

Tags: php, forms, input

I have a form that I process in PHP.  Users sometimes put their email address in the form or URLs.  These usually come out as text after I strip the input of tags.

Recently my users started asking me to make their URLs and emails clickable when they pull up a page that displays their input (now pulled from a db).

Could someone please suggest a common pattern or ways that this is handled?  Basically, if someone enters a url in a form, how do I make the url clickable instead of text when viewed?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I don't get it. You mean having a clickable link inside an input field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression based function like this

```
function  autolink($message) { 
    //Convert all urls to links
    $message = preg_replace('#([\s|^])(www)#i', '$1http://$2', $message);
    $pattern = '#((http|https|ftp|telnet|news|gopher|file|wais):\/\/[^\s]+)#i';
    $replacement = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>';
    $message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);

    /* Convert all E-mail matches to appropriate HTML links */
    $pattern = '#([0-9a-z]([-_.]?[0-9a-z])*@[0-9a-z]([-.]?[0-9a-z])*\\.';
    $pattern .= '[a-wyz][a-z](fo|g|l|m|mes|o|op|pa|ro|seum|t|u|v|z)?)#i';
    $replacement = '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>';
    $message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message);
    return $message;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to wrap the url in a anchor tag:

assuming `$myLink` is the link text coming from your db:

```
<a href="<?php echo $myLink; ?>"><?php echo $myLink; ?></a>
```

Comment: You know, the problem I am facing is that the input is free-written, so I don't know if the input will be text, url, or email.  So I wouldn't know that I have a $myLink variable.

Comment: in that case, youre going to have to do some regex checking first to see if the text is a url.